# IS it OK to flash stock ROM from other country?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

Is it OK if I flash my phone with a stock ROM from another country? Wouldn't it have a negative effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to flash stock ROM from another country. BUT, take note that it may have different languages, and a different baseband/modem. Having a different baseband can cause network issues (or a very hot phone), but you can flash a baseband that works for your country.

Comment: You can also flash the baseband separately from the ROM.